# Eloquent default skipping column like deleted_at

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on ecommerce project in Laravel framework.

There is an option like disable the products.

If the product is disabled the column status will be 0.

Is there any option to set skip the results whose status is 0 in default, like skipping deleted_at column if it is not null?

Comment: Something like: `$products = Product::where('status', '<>', 0)->get();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **scopes**:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', '<>', 0);
    }
...
```

And use it like that:

```
App\Product::active()->get();
```

See the official scopes documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes).

Comment: thank you very much. and In one place I want to show the disable products in there how do I avoid global scope?

Comment: This are local scopes. Just add another scope: `public function scopeInactive($query) { return $query->where('status', '=', 0);}`

Comment: I made the scope like whenever I use `Product::all()` it shows all the products except disabled. In one place alone I need to show disabled product. is there anything like `Model::withTrashed()->get();`. This will show column even it is soft deleted